# How many have a name longer than 10 characters in xlsx matlab

Tags: matlab

How many elements have a name longer than 10 characters in xlsx matlab?
I tried this.

```
[number cities] = xlsread('weather.xlsx', 'city')
if cities{1}<=char(10); 
    x+1=x;
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop, iterate over all cities. You probably need `size` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above only checks to see if the **first** city has less than 10 characters.  Also, `char(10)` does not make any sense.  You are checking to see if the string contained in `cities{1}` is less than or equal to the character array containing `10`.

Because `cities` is in a cell array, I would use `cellfun` to first return the length of each city.  Then you can use a `sum` as well as a Boolean condition to help you figure out how many there are that have more than 10 characters.

As such, here is the code:

```
A = cellfun(@length, cities);
numCitiesMoreThan10 = sum(A > 10);
```

Here is an example (simulated):

```
cities = {'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Toronto', 'Ottawa', 'Sydney', 'Melbourne', ...
          'Timbuktu', 'Singapore', 'Mississippi'};

A = cellfun(@length, cities);
numCitiesMoreThan10 = sum(A > 10);

>> numCitiesMoreThan10 = 

   2
```

This makes sense, as the only two cities with more than 10 characters (including spaces) are Los Angeles and Mississippi.

### Aside

Just learned that `cellfun` has something built-in that can do this.  You can also do:

```
A = cellfun('size', cities, 2);
```

This accesses each element in the cell array (`cities`), and returns the size of whatever dimension you specify in the last parameter of `cellfun` when you call it with the `size` parameter.  You can also chain more than one cell array together.  The reason why you are choosing the third parameter as `2` is because each string in the cell array is a `1 x N` array.  As such, we need to read how many columns there are so that this equates to the length of each string.

Comment: `@(x) length(x)` is a bit pointless, you can just use `@length`  Or `@numel`